# Using following shell script to find data on web with given username and password

Tags: shell, curl, wget

The following code successfully prints those files that contains both- string1 and string2. However I want this functionality to find the same on a given ip-address as well given userame and password. Kindly suggest some modifications to incorporate this functionality

```
for file in `find -name "*.java"`
do
    grep -q "string1" $file && grep -q "string2" $file && echo  "\n`basename     $file`"

done
```

Answer (score 0):

For making a search of a file on a remote machine is never been easy.

But in case you really want to do it and you have rights to make a search on remote computer, you might want to follow below steps.

1) First of all I believe your current shell script is too naive. You will need to improve it by [THIS FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/008)

2) Now, you need to learn to build the basic .xml file through ANT. YOu will need to learn it to use it's SSHEXEC functionality. which will execute the shell script on remote machine

3) Ensure FTP service is up and put a shell script on remote machine through FTP.

4) Execute that through ANT build and write back the data.

I am suggesting this considering you want to run shell script "ON REMOTE MACHINE" (NOT WEB) and you are allowed to enter into that machine through FTP and SSH.